# Fit XAML path into view

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following path. The data is from some data file:

```
<Path StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" Data="M 30330.8847248349,-37724.909002528 L 28556.3829935257,-37596.5557453925 28031.7660050946,-38008.0608378072 27746.4689258268,-38895.6687979239 27655.7148993139,-39397.1764657993 27718.5888966473,-39755.4955438608 27628.0246979519,-40621.440862981 28514.7500540091,-41208.8847446069 29093.8320242864,-40459.5872073251 29768.3831435369,-40107.7166927063 30092.4525793664,-39483.6045857995 30784.2658266352,-38627.7070622611 30811.846313938,-38537.1499823241 30358.6906348136,-37734.2759127391 30330.8847248349,-37724.909002528" />
```

I like to know what this looks like, so I want to render it in Kaxaml or XamlPad. Is there an easy way to resize this path so it will render nicely centered on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the path's stretch attribute to Uniform to maitain the apsect ratio and you should be able to see it in KaXaml

```
    <Path Stretch="Uniform" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" Data="M 30330.8847248349,-37724.909002528 L 28556.3829935257,-37596.5557453925 28031.7660050946,-38008.0608378072 27746.4689258268,-38895.6687979239 27655.7148993139,-39397.1764657993 27718.5888966473,-39755.4955438608 27628.0246979519,-40621.440862981 28514.7500540091,-41208.8847446069 29093.8320242864,-40459.5872073251 29768.3831435369,-40107.7166927063 30092.4525793664,-39483.6045857995 30784.2658266352,-38627.7070622611 30811.846313938,-38537.1499823241 30358.6906348136,-37734.2759127391 30330.8847248349,-37724.909002528" />
```