# Center multiple XAML paths into view

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Now this question looks similar to the question I've [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789321/fit-xaml-path-into-view), however, this time I have multiple Path objects. I want to create a control that centers the paths nicely. Example:

```
<Grid>  
    <Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 3,3 L 7,4 3,12 3,3" />
    <Path Stroke="Black" Data="M 3,6 L 7,4 12,6 3,6" />
</Grid>
```

Is there an easy way to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this in code-behind. I calculated the minimum and maximum values (for X/Y) in my geometry. I applied a ScaleTransform with a calculated zoom factor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain what effect you want, if you use Stretch="Fill" on the path objects, it will center them and stretch them. I presume you want to just center them though? However what does HorizontalAlignment="Center" and VerticalAlignment="Center" do if you set Stretch="Uniform" on each path?

Comment: This is not the effect I'm after. I want the objects to stay in their relative position, only change the zoom factor.